# Edit a list of json files with the file name of the json files in R

Tags: r, json

I'm using R.
I have a group of json files like this:

file1.json
file2.json
file3.json

Each file has the same structure with several events inside organised like this

```
{
    "id": MEME1,
    "created_at": 55796,
    "text": "patatipatata",
    "Perso": {
        "id": "MEMEuk",      
},

{
    "id": MEME2,
    "created_at": 55795,
    "text": "lolme",
    "Perso": {
        "id": "MEMEfr",
        
}
```

I would like to edit each json file with the name of the initial file for each events like this for the file1.json and the others

```
{
    "file_name": file1.json,
    "id": MEME,
    "created_at": 55796,
    "text": "patatipatata",
    "Perso": {
        "id": "MEMEuk",
        

},
{
    "file_name": file1.json,        
    "id": MEME2,
    "created_at": 55795,
    "text": "lolme",
    "Perso": {
        "id": "MEMEfr",
        
}
```

I'm not really familiar with json structure and json edition with R.
The final objective is to merge and flatten the group of json files and to get a vector with the name of the original file for each events. This last part is ok to me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Those files are not valid json (`MEME1` should be quoted, the embedded dictionary is not closed out, and the should be enclosed in list brackets `[`/`]`). Is it safe to fix it, or are your files truly invalid and need to remain that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those files are invalid json files, for several reasons. I'll fix the errors so that they parse correctly.

- **file1.json**

  ```
  [{
      "id": "MEME1",
      "created_at": 55796,
      "text": "patatipatata",
      "Perso": {
          "id": "MEMEuk"
      }
  },
  {
      "id": "MEME2",
      "created_at": 55795,
      "text": "lolme",
      "Perso": {
          "id": "MEMEfr"
      }
  }]
  ```
- **file2.json** (simplified)

  ```
  [{
      "id": "MEME3",
      "created_at": 55796
  },
  {
      "id": "MEME2",
      "created_at": 55795
  }]
  ```

### Read them in:

```r
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.json$", full.names = TRUE)
files
# [1] "./file1.json" "./file2.json"
alldat <- lapply(setNames(nm = files), jsonlite::read_json)

str(alldat[[2]]) # files[2], aka 'file2.json'
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ id        : chr "MEME3"
#   ..$ created_at: int 55796
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ id        : chr "MEME2"
#   ..$ created_at: int 55795
```

### Inserting the filename

```r
alldat2 <- Map(function(nm, onedat) {
  lapply(onedat, function(x) {
    x$file_name <- nm
    x
  })
}, names(alldat), alldat)

str(alldat2[[2]])
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ id        : chr "MEME3"
#   ..$ created_at: int 55796
#   ..$ file_name : chr "./file2.json"
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ id        : chr "MEME2"
#   ..$ created_at: int 55795
#   ..$ file_name : chr "./file2.json"
```

### Write back to file

```r
Map(function(onedat, fn) jsonlite::write_json(onedat, fn, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE),
    alldat2, files)
# $`./file1.json`
# NULL
# $`./file2.json`
# NULL

readLines(files[2])
#  [1] "["                                  
#  [2] "  {"                                
#  [3] "    \"id\": \"MEME3\","             
#  [4] "    \"created_at\": 55796,"         
#  [5] "    \"file_name\": \"./file2.json\""
#  [6] "  },"                               
#  [7] "  {"                                
#  [8] "    \"id\": \"MEME2\","             
#  [9] "    \"created_at\": 55795,"         
# [10] "    \"file_name\": \"./file2.json\""
# [11] "  }"                                
# [12] "]"
```

It might not be guaranteed that they look *precisely* as they did before read-in, though the structure (and json parseability) should be fine.

Comment: This worked for me until the part Inserting the filename and the alldat2 file creation. Then the json changed and is not easy to flatten but I managed to do so. Thanks r2evans.